# How to install jshint in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jshint

How can I properly initial JSHINT to find errors in the `id="text-intro"` script element. How do I complete the `function main()` so that

1) The working data of JSHINT is set to the content of `id="text-intro"`.

2) A array of founds errors is correctly reported by JSHINT.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="static.cache.cdn/js/jshint.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


  <script id="text-intro" type="text/jshint">
      // Hello.
      //
      // This is JSHint, a tool that helps to detect errors and potential
      // problems in your JavaScript code.
      //
      // To start, simply enter some JavaScript anywhere on this page. Your
      // report will appear on the right side.
      //
      // Additionally, you can toggle specific options in the Configure
      // menu.

      function main() {
        return 'Hello, World!';
      }

      main();
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function main()
    {
        JSHINT. ... ?
    }
    main();
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably put what you are trying to do in the question, otherwise people will assume you are just trying to use JSHint as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, I think.

```
  ... truncated ...

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function main()
    {
        var scriptContent = document.getElementById('text-intro').textContent;
        // You can symbols here for jsHint to assume are existing.
        var globals = {
            jQuery: true // Assume that jQuery is defined and don't report it as an error.  
        };
        // Options to pass to jshint, see the docs.  Here are some examples.
        var options = {
            /* '-W034': true */
            /* 'camelcase': true */
            /* 'predef': ['-window'] //  remove a normally predefined var */
            /* exported: ['MyVar'] // tell jshint this var is used in another file */
        };
        JSHINT(scriptContent, options, globals);
        // Now do something with JSHINT.errors
    }
    main();
  </script>
```